# How to start GUI of Deja Dup in Debian 8.1?

Tags: backup, gui, dejadup

I installed Deja dup by `sudo apt-get install deja-dup` but I cannot find it in Search. 
It appears in commandline, but not like in Ubuntu like [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/dj-dup-perfect-linux-backup-software/).
I did not find any GUI for deja-dup in `apt-cache search`/`apt-file search`. 
I only find the application `backups` in GUI Search but it is not apparently deja-dup.

How can you install GUI of Deja-dup in Debian 8.1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

command is "deja-dup-preferences"
just create a menu item on whatever desktop you are using that executes the above command and a GUI will open up on your desktop